ReadTheDocs: trigger build only for a given folder
I have a ReadTheDocs project set up with an integration/webhook so that it builds when the develop branch of my Github repo is updated.
The problem is that this triggers a build any time I push to the develop branch, and I want to build only when pushing a commit to the docs/ folder of that branch (which obviously contains the documentation).
Can this be achieved?

It depends on the integration; when using GitHub Actions to build a page or trigger a workflow, you can filter by path (paths parameter).

You configure your Read the Docs builds to skip building the docs if there are no changes in that directory by running a commit and exiting with 183 exit code. Take a look at the documentation https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/build-customization.html#cancel-build-based-on-a-condition
